# How can I adjust my model to avoid a logits shape [32,1180] and labels shape [640] mismatch?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, lstm

The input data X and the labels y have the same shape when they are passed into the model. The ultimate task is to predict future smart device events from an input event or event sequence. The loss function I am using is spare_categorical_cross entropy.

X.shape = (1179, 20)
y.shape = (1179, 20)

It seems after the data is input into the model the y labels get distorted based on th error I am receiving below.

```
InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Node: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [32,1180] and labels shape [640]
     [[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_674783]
```

Here is the model I am using below and the model fit function. I have it in a loop because I am training different models sequentially based on subsets from the original dataset I have.

Any recommendations and help would be greatly appreciated

```
vocab_size = len(tokenized_sequences[key]) + 1

    input_layer = Input(shape=(max_sequence_length,))
    embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, 128, input_length=max_sequence_length)(input_layer)
    lstm_layer = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))(embedding_layer)
    lstm_layer_2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))(lstm_layer)
    lstm_layer_3 = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))(lstm_layer_2)
    flatten_layer = Flatten()(lstm_layer_3)
    
    # Add the custom attention layer after the last LSTM layer
    #attention_weights = AttentionLayer()(lstm_layer_3)
    #attention_output = tf.reduce_sum(attention_weights[..., tf.newaxis] * lstm_layer_3, axis=2)
    
    # Add dense layers after the attention output
    dense_layer_1 = Dense(512, activation='relu')(flatten_layer)
    dense_layer_2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(dense_layer_1)

    output_layer = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(dense_layer_2)
    
    model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer, name=f'model_{key}')
    
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```
# Set the directory where you want to save the trained models
models_folder = 'models'
os.makedirs(models_folder, exist_ok=True)

# Set training parameters
epochs = 100
batch_size = 32
validation_split = 0.2

#attention_models = {}

# Fit the models and save them
for key, model in models.items():
    # Prepare the input data and labels
    X = tokenized_sequences[key]
    y = tokenized_labels[key]
    
    print(X.shape)
    print(y.shape)
    
    early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=15, restore_best_weights=True)

    # Fit the model
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=validation_split, callbacks=[early_stopping])

    # Save the trained model
    model.save(os.path.join(models_folder, f'model_{key}.h5'))
```

I tried inputting the X and y as the same shape, but somehow the y gets distorted from the shape (1179, 20) to (640,). It seems the model is multiplying the max_sequence_length of 20 by the batch size 32. The result is this long error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [135], line 28
     25 early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=15, restore_best_weights=True)
     27 # Fit the model
---> 28 model.fit(X, y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=validation_split, callbacks=[early_stopping])
     30 # Save the trained model
     31 model.save(os.path.join(models_folder, f'model_{key}.h5'))

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:52, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50 try:
     51   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     55   if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 982, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 505, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 215, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 570, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1859, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 81, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 687, in <lambda>
      lambda f: self._run_callback(functools.partial(callback, future))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 740, in _run_callback
      ret = callback()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 821, in inner
      self.ctx_run(self.run)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 782, in run
      yielded = self.gen.send(value)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 365, in process_one
      yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 272, in dispatch_shell
      yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 540, in execute_request
      self.do_execute(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 294, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 536, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2940, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2995, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3194, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3373, in run_ast_nodes
      if await self.run_code(code, result, async_=asy):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3433, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-135-3fce51198083>", line 28, in <module>
      model.fit(X, y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=validation_split, callbacks=[early_stopping])
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1650, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1233, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1222, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1024, in train_step
      loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1082, in compute_loss
      return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
      loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 152, in __call__
      losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 284, in call
      return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 2098, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
      return backend.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5633, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
      res = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
Node: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [32,1180] and labels shape [640]
     [[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_674783]
```